# How to solve error with the html tags in angular?

Tags: html, angular, html-parsing

I get the following error when I wrote some HTML code to build a nav bar.

Errors parsing template: Unexpected closing tag "li". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("

```
  `<li><a href="#">Recipies</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Shopping List/a>[ERROR ->]</li>
   </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> "): `



<div class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class='navbar-brand'>Recipe Book</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-new">
            <li><a href="#">Recipies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping List/a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fetch Data`</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help and explain what is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo

```
<li><a href="#">Shopping List/a></li>
```

missed the left bracket

```
<li><a href="#">Shopping List </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <li><a href="#">Fetch Data ` </a></li>
> ```

On your second list item you've a backtick alone behind the "data" word